# Make Reduce produce nicer output

Tags: equation-solving, output-formatting, inequalities

I am trying to reduce a bunch of inequalities using the Reduce command in Mathematica. But the output is very convoluted and I am wondering if there's a way to systematically organize it so that I can actually write it on a piece of paper, or at the very least, read it correctly.

For example,

```
Reduce[h1>=0 && h2>=0 && 2*x>=0 && -m+h1+y>=0 && m+x-y>=0 && h2-x+2y>=0, {x,y}]
```

produces output that looks like this

[image]

which, needless to say, looks horrendous.

Is there a way to clean this up?

Comment: The output is systematically organized in a [Cylindrical algebraic decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_algebraic_decomposition) -- if you learn what it means you'll find it easier to use.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelE2. Knowing what it is doesn't help me read the output as cleanly as I would like, but thanks for enlightening me about CAD.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are OK with turning the `Or`s into `Column`s, you can do something like:

```
result = Reduce[
   h1 >= 0 && h2 >= 0 && 2*x >= 0 && -m + h1 + y >= 0 && 
    m + x - y >= 0 && h2 - x + 2 y >= 0, {x, y}];

TraditionalForm[
 result //. 
   {Or -> (Column[#, Right, Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, Frame -> All] &)@*List}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Your code does not work on MMA Version 8,0.  What should `@*List ` be?

Comment: @Akku14 See [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html)

Comment: Thank you @chuy for the response. This is very nice.

Comment: @Michael E2, thanks for the hint. This is the only code, that works in version 8.0   `TraditionalForm[
 result //. 
  Or -> Composition[(Column[#, Right, 
       Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, Frame -> All] &), List]] `