# Simultaneous equation

Tags: number-theory

How to solve Simultaneous equation in Mathematica:

`x^2 - (a^2 - 1)y^2 = 1`  and `y^2 - pz^2 = 1` where  `0< a < 16` and `0 < y < 100` and `0 < p < 50` and `0 < z < 100`.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It's very discouraging to see questions that show little effort. If you expect to inspire anybody to **volunteer their time to look at your problem**, then start by doing your part. Read the Mathematica documentation. Get the *Informed* badge in the site by taking and understanding the [tour]. Please write your equations in Wolfram Mathematica language (Also in $\LaTeX$ if that helps). To add new information [edit] your  question, use the *comments* section just for comments.

Answer (score 4):

*(Referring to the answer by @chuy  in ["Make Reduce produce nicer output"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/173913/38178)).*

Regarding `a` and `p` as parameters and `x`, `y`, `z` as variables.

```
red = Reduce[{x^2 - (a^2 - 1) y^2 == 1 , y^2 - p z^2 == 1, 0 < a < 16,
 0 < y < 100 , 0 < p < 50 , 0 < z < 100}, {x, y, z}, Reals];

TraditionalForm[
   red //. Or -> 
   Composition[(Column[#, Right, Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, 
   Frame -> All] &), List]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentations for [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) and [`Assuming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html). And understand the difference between [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)(`=`) and [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)(`==`).

```
Assuming[
 {0 < a < 16,
  0 < y < 100,
  0 < p < 50,
  0 < z < 100},
 Solve[{
   x^2 - (a^2 - 1) y^2 == 1,
     y^2 - p z^2 == 1
   }]
 ]
```

> $\left\{\\
> \left\{p\to \frac{y^2-1}{z^2},x\to -\sqrt{a^2 y^2-y^2+1}\right\},\\
> \left\{p\to \frac{y^2-1}{z^2},x\to \sqrt{a^2 y^2-y^2+1}\right\},\\
> \{x\to -a,y\to -1,z\to 0\},\\
> \{x\to  a,y\to -1,z\to 0\},\\
> \{x\to -a,y\to 1,z\to 0\},\\
> \{x\to a,y\to 1,z\to 0\}\\
> \right\}$

Comment: To @rhermans. I think, since the OP gives conditons for `p` and `z` , the `pz`  is simply a typo. You should regard it as `p*z` .

Comment: @Akku14 thanks, I think you are right. It's corrected now.